# Spring Security One-Time-Password (OTP) based Login

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, one-time-password

I'm implementing a web application using Spring Boot and I wanna know is there any best practice to leverage Spring Security in the following security model.

- End-Users will register into the service via an SMS OTP service (providing their mobile number). once they have validated the OTP code, their user gets created (using their mobile number as username).
- Upon successful OTP registration, I want the user to be able to use the service (on the same device through which the OTP registration performed before) without the need to re-confirm his identity again (Same functionality we can see in native mobile apps such as Whatsaap, Instagram or Telegram)

I appreciate any ideas or instructions on this subject.

Comment: I guess an 'OTP registration/validation' is similar to normal login. Assuming that user enters the OTP in a form (that also has hidden user's id) and submits it, OTP value is processed through the same authentication providers - except that instead of a regular password, user's OTP record is checked.

Comment: Dear Ritesh,
Thanks for the comment, but my concern is different than OTP authentication itself, yes you are right, the OTP authentication takes place the same way as normal user/password model.
But I am looking for a mechanism to keep letting the OTP authenticated user to use my application, no matter how many times he/she exits and re-enter the app or close the browser and come back again.
We experience the same thing here on Stackoverflow website as well. you only need to login to the website once and from that point on, whenever you open it, it won't ask for your credentials again,

Comment: I believe the potential solution has to have some business with the cookies (the session opened between client and server) but I'm looking for a best practice specific to Spring Security, via which I could guarantee my application's security without loosing too much performance by storing and keeping all the unnecessary open sessions in back-end.

Comment: Hi @Majid have you found solution for your problem. I am also stuck in a similar use case. I could use your help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61804081/replace-spring-security-login-with-otp-verification

Comment: I had the similar use case, try checking my example project from here https://github.com/CodingWithTashi/spring-boot-otp-login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Answer is to use Spring Security using the "remember me" feature.
[Here](https://www.boraji.com/spring-security-5-remember-me-authentication-example), there is a thorough tutorial about that