# Replace Spring Security Login with OTP Verification

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a following tables

```
User table

    -username
    -password
    -mobile

OTP
    -mobile
    -otpCode
    -expiry
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
    .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/loginAction").permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll()
    .and()
    .csrf().disable();
```

When I attempt login. Spring Security checks *User* table for *username* and *password*.
My Use-case is login screen is customised to send otp and Authentication should happen in this flow

1. Check *Username* from *User* table
2. Check *otpCode* for corresponding user's mobile in *OTP* table
3. If matches flow should complete successful authentication.

Comment: Try building a custom Authentication Provider! https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider

Comment: You can also look at this code. https://github.com/upcrob/spring-security-otp